# Prompt a Msgbox and delete if duplicates are found in excel

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, msgbox

I am using  following line to remove *duplicates* in column.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 1), Header:=xlYes
```

Problem is, this is done silently and I don't really know when my data has double values.

I need know by using `Msgbox` that if duplicates are deleted or not. Is it possible using `Count` to mention number of entries deleted? in simplest code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You can count the rows before removing Duplicates
- Then display the msgbox after counting rows again and Subtracting from Previous count

---

**Try:**

```
Dim lr As Long
With ActiveSheet

    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    .Range("A:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 1), Header:=xlYes

    If Not lr - .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row = 0 Then
        MsgBox lr - .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row & " Rows Deleted"
    End If
End With
```

Comment: I don't need Msgbox when there is no entry deleted. can you counter that?

Comment: yes thanks! but I need to use it for day to make sure that I don't need anything else out of it.